# Javascript - using regex to match all instances of 3 consecutive numbers?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find all instances of 3 consecutive digits using a regex.

```
num = "12224999011112"
num.match(/(.){3}/g)
=> ["122", "249", "990", "111"]
```

I expected to obtain numbers like `222`, `224` and `499` to be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you need an array of overlapping numbers.

You need to use a positive look-ahead with a capturing group inside it:

```
(?=(\d{3}))
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cO0iS8/1)

```js
var re = /(?=(\d{3}))/g; 
var str = '12224999011112';
var arr = []; 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML += m[1] + "<br/>";
    arr.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<div id="res"/>
```

Comment: Does it work for you or do you need further assistance?